# ActiveMQ onMessage never works with createDurableSubscriber

Tags: kotlin, jms, activemq-classic

I have been trying to find out why `onMessage` is not getting invoked in the below code. I am able to publish a set of objects to a Topic name "SampleTopic" successfully, but I am not able to consume from it.  Nothing has worked for me. Please suggest.

```
val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}
logger.info { "This is info log : Inside subscriber" }

val connFactory = ActiveMQConnectionFactory()
val conn = connFactory.createConnection()!!
conn.setClientID("SampleClient")
val sess = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
val dest = sess.createTopic("SampleTopic")
val cons : TopicSubscriber = sess.createDurableSubscriber(dest, "SampleSubscription")

logger.info { "This is info log : Inside subscriber $cons" }
conn.start()
Thread.sleep(10000)
logger.info { "This is info log : Inside subscriber $cons" }

cons.setMessageListener { 
    MessageListener() {
        fun onMessage(message: Message?) {
            try {
                logger.info { "This is info log : Inside subscriber1 : $message" }
            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: JMSException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}

logger.info { "This is info log : Inside subscriber90 $cons" }
conn.close()
```

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9OYh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you set the `MessageListener` you invoke `close()` on the connection. Closing the connection will close all related sessions along with all the producers and consumers created from those sessions. Therefore you won't be able to receive any messages. Once you set the `MessageListener` you'll need to keep the connection *open* so it can receive messages.

Keep in mind that the purpose of the `MessageListener` is to receive messages *asynchronously*. You need to keep the connection open during this time.

The *simplest* way to keep the connection open is just to insert a `Thread.sleep()` after you set the `MessageListener`. However, this effectively makes your client synchronous.

Alternatively, you can receive messages synchronously. This bit of code will consume all the messages it can until it doesn't receive a message for 10 seconds:

```
val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}
logger.info { "This is info log : Inside subscriber" }

val connFactory = ActiveMQConnectionFactory()
val conn = connFactory.createConnection()!!
conn.setClientID("SampleClient")
val sess = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
val dest = sess.createTopic("SampleTopic")
val cons : TopicSubscriber = sess.createDurableSubscriber(dest, "SampleSubscription")

logger.info { "This is info log : Inside subscriber $cons" }
conn.start()
Thread.sleep(10000)
logger.info { "This is info log : Inside subscriber $cons" }

do {
    val message = cons.receive(10000)
    logger.info { "This is info log : $message" }
} while (message != null)

logger.info { "This is info log : Inside subscriber90 $cons" }
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you tell me how to keep connection open till all msgs are read asynchronously. I commented conn.close, but it’s still the same. I want to read msgs asynchronous way. If any leads pls provide.

Comment: If you just commented out `conn.close()` then the method and the application probably just exited which is effectively the same thing as closing the connection.  I updated my answer to provide additional help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again, the issue is one time the consumer reads messages from topic the other time it doesnot, even though it has some msgs enqueued it. I run activemq locally in my system and after that I try many times but it doesnot read msgs, val message = cons.receive(10000) always returns null.

Comment: How are you confirming that there are messages in the subscription?

Comment: I see this in the activeMQ page -> Producer Topic 1 100 0
(100 msgs enqueued), my producer and consumer topic are same.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of this to your question and add details about the problem?

Comment: sure, can we chat about this? How to contact you pls?

Comment: If you really need to chat you can find me on the #activemq channel on the ASF Slack mentioned [here](https://activemq.apache.org/contact). However, it's probably best to just work here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: sure, I have added screenshot now

Comment: How many subscriptions exist on that topic?

Comment: 2 subscriptions, have added the screenshot for the same

Comment: Thanks Justin a lot, I was able to make progress, the issue was I made the durable subscriber offline always, I ran the pub and sub separately and it worked. Hope my understanding is right. Is there any way I can keep my durable subscriber always active ?

Comment: We're pretty deep into the comments at this point so it might be worth asking a new, separate question. If my answer addressed your original question (which, if you are able to consumer at least some messages, I think it did) then mark it as correct to help other users who run into this same problem in the future.

Comment: Thanks Jutin, just accepted your answer.